# Counting how many times a word occurs in a map - using transform() - no match for call to

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, vector, cpu-word

I'm trying to count how many times a word exists in a map. The map is then supposed to contain the word as a string and the number of times it exists as an int. inlist is the vector with all the words. I first create a map with the first transform() and then I want to use the second transform() to change the ints in the map using the function counter()

```
void input_a(vector<string> inlist)
{
    map<string, int> wordcount;

    transform(inlist.begin(), inlist.end(), inserter(wordcount, wordcount.end()), [] (string c){return make_pair(c, 0);});

    transform(wordcount.begin(), wordcount.end(), wordcount.begin(), [&inlist] (string c){return counter(c, inlist);});
```

The function counter() returns a pair because that's what I want to insert in the map.

```
pair <string, int> counter(string word, vector<string> list)
{
    int n{1};
    n = count(list.begin(), list.end(), word);

    return make_pair(word, n);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/algorithm:62:0,
                 from wordlist.h:7,
                 from wordlist.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_OIter std::transform(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _UnaryOperation) [with _IIter = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; _OIter = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; _UnaryOperation = input_a(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >)::<lambda(std::__cxx11::string)>]’:
wordlist.cc:75:118:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:4306:24: error: no match for call to ‘(input_a(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >)::<lambda(std::__cxx11::string)>) (std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)’
  *__result = __unary_op(*__first);
              ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
wordlist.cc:75:89: note: candidate: input_a(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >)::<lambda(std::__cxx11::string)>
 unt.begin(), wordcount.end(), wordcount.begin(), [&inlist] (string c){return counter(c, inlist);});
                                                                     ^
wordlist.cc:75:89: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>’ to ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’
```

Comment: Lambda should take a `std::pair`. `std::map` "consists" of pairs, and these pairs are fed into lambda by `std::transform`.

Comment: What is lambda?

Comment: @ohan820 You may not change keys if a map.

Comment: Lambda is this beast: `[&inlist] (string c){ ... }`.

Comment: " I first create a map with the first transform() and then I want to use the second transform() to change the ints in the map using the function counter()" why if you can count just in one pass? Just in sake of using `std::transform`?

Comment: @evg so what would be the allowed syntax? Should it be [&inlist](string c, int i) instead?

Comment: @SlavasupportsMonica That worked and is a way simpler solution. Thank you!

Comment: It should be `[...](std::pair<const std::string, int>&) {...}`.

Answer (score 1):

In this call

```
transform(wordcount.begin(), wordcount.end(), wordcount.begin(), [&inlist] (string c){return counter(c, inlist);});
```

you are trying to change keys of the map.

That is pairs in the map have the type `std::pair<const std::string, int>`. You may not reassign such a pair.

All you need is the following

```
void input_a( const std::vector<std::string> &inlist )
{
    std::map<std::string, int> wordcount;

    for ( const auto &item : inlist ) ++wordcount[item];
    // ...
}
```

It is more efficient than to traverse the vector many times.

Comment: I believe main culprit is not traversing vector two times but doing lookups in the `std::map` 2 times for each word in the vector